# How to match events in two causal streams to detect excessive lagging

Tags: system.reactive

I have two hot observables, which are respectively a stream `Q` of requests to a network server, and a stream `R` of replies from the server. The replies are always delivered in the order of requests, and every request is going to receive exactly one reply *eventually*. Thus the first event in `R`, *R<sub>1</sub>*, is the reply to the first event in `Q`, *Q<sub>1</sub>*, and so on. I need to detect when a reply *Rn* takes longer than a defined timeout and signal this timeout condition.

```
  Q --1---2---------3------->  // Requests Q1, Q2...
  R ----1------------------->  // Replies
Out ------------------O-|>     // Oops: Reply R2 to Q2 did not arrive within time τ.
          |<----τ---->|
```

Events *Qn* and *Rn* do not contain any identifying information (think of plain colorless round marbles), and the indices in the diagram are just sequential numbers introduced for explanation.

I seem unable to solve this riddle. I tried the approach below, but it appears I am matching *the latest* request *Q<sub>i</sub>* to *the latest* response *R<sub>j</sub>*. In the sample `Q` contains 5 requests, spaced 500ms apart, and replies in `R` come 750ms apart, starting at 200ms, but only 4 of them (the 5th is delayed indefinitely). The code does not detect that, since that last reply R<sub>4</sub> comes within the set timeout of 1000ms after the *latest* request Q<sub>5</sub> (in 200ms, actually).

```cs
var Q = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)).Select(_ => Unit.Default)
                   .Take(5).Concat(Observable.Never<Unit>());
var R = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(750)).Select(_ => Unit.Default)
                   .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200))
                   .Take(4).Concat(Observable.Never<Unit>());

var dq = Q.Select(v => Observable.Return(v).Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)));
var dr = Observable.Zip(Q, R, (_1,_2) => Observable.Never<Unit>());
Observable.Merge(dq, dr).Dump().Switch().Dump();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want to be notified that request 4 has timed out (due at 3s, but arrives at 3.2s) and also request 5 as it never arrives

```cs
void Main()
{
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    var requests = scheduler.CreateHotObservable<int>(
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(0500.Ms(), 1),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(1000.Ms(), 2),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(1500.Ms(), 3),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(2000.Ms(), 4),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(2500.Ms(), 5));
    var responses = scheduler.CreateHotObservable<Unit>(
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(0950.Ms(), Unit.Default),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(1700.Ms(), Unit.Default),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(2450.Ms(), Unit.Default),
        ReactiveTest.OnNext(3200.Ms(), Unit.Default));

    var expected = scheduler.CreateHotObservable<int>(
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(3000.Ms(), 4),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(3500.Ms(), 5)
            );

    var observer = scheduler.CreateObserver<int>();

    var query = responses
        .Select((val, idx)=>idx)
        .Publish(responseIdxs =>
    {
        return requests.SelectMany((q, qIdx) =>
                Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), scheduler)
                    .TakeUntil(responseIdxs.Where(rIdx => qIdx == rIdx))
                    .Select(_ => q));
    });

    query.Subscribe(observer);
    scheduler.Start();

    //This test passes
    ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(
        expected.Messages,
        observer.Messages);

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static class TickExtensions
{
    public static long Ms(this int ms)
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ms).Ticks;
    }
}
```

Comment: He said that there's nothing identifying about qn or rn, so you can't use q == r. You have to match by index (use indexed SelectMany on requests, then use index to skip responses), or cheat and add an identifier somewhere.

Comment: But he also states that the responses will always be in order, so the conditional check is valid

Comment: ... For my sample data. But yes, he could switch out to use the index from `Select`

Comment: If you switch the integers to `Unit.Default`, like the question, the test fails.

Comment: If you have `{q1@0, q2@500, r1@800, r2@2000}`, and use `Unit.Default`, your code will pass it, because the `Unit` returned `r1@800` will satisfy both `q1` and `q2` requirements, when it should only satisfy `q1`.

Comment: @Shlomo: It's too easy to number messages in both stream with `.Select((_, n) => n)`

Comment: @LeeCampbell: Thanks for the update, and I too noticed that `responseIdxs` must be published hot. I'm taking a liberty of adding an SO language tag to your answer so that syntax highlighting works.